# Winform app command line arguments IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform app and I put arguments "1-2-c:\temp-test" into Command Line arguments text box under Debug tab of Project property. The code as follows to read.

```
String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

string exeFilename = arguments[0]; 
string temp = arguments[1]; // return the argument string value. e.g."1-2-c:\temp-test" 



string[] args = temp.Split('-');
  try
        {
            string first = "", second="", third="", fourth = "";
            if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
            {
                first = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]) ? "1" : args[0];
                second = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1]) ? "2" : args[1];
                third = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[2]) ? @"c:\temp\" : args[2];
                fourth = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[3]) ? "test" : args[3];



            }
catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string argsTest  = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
                argsTest = args[0];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1]))
                argsTest = argsTest + " "+ args[1];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[2]))
                argsTest = argsTest + " " + args[2];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[3]))
                argsTest = argsTest + " " + args[3];


            MessageBox.Show(argsTest + " \n Error:  " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

when I run application form visual studio, it works fine  but when I go to bin\debug and double click .exe file, I am getting the IndexOutOfRangeException exception.

Another observation, If I execute this exe with arguments from command prompt, it works fine.

Exception raised when I double click my exe file.

I searched and spent time to resolve but did not get any solution. I am totally stuck. Any kind of hints/code/advice is appreciable.

Comment: I'd recommend [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) to spare you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

When you're opening it via the .exe file, you're not supplying it any arguments. Make sure you're using some method to provide arguments when opening the .exe (from command prompt, or hard coding something in to test).

Comment: And of course add a check before accessing the 2nd argument!!! Better exit gracefully with a message 'No arguments provided, exiting.'

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run from the executable you have to pass in the command line arguments. This can be done in one of two common ways:

1. Create a batch file that calls the executable with suitable arguments.
2. Create a shortcut and modify the Target to have the arguments on the end.

On a separate note you should probably check that your arguments have been supplied. i.e.

```
if (arguments.Length >= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `args.Length` when you want address an item at specific index, not for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[...])`:

```
...
String first = (args.Length > 0) ? args[0] : "1";
String second = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : "2";
String third = (args.Length > 2) ? args[2] : @"c:\temp\";
String fourth = (args.Length > 3) ? args[3] : "test";

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting debug commands in visual studio will not "embed" them in the `exe` file. It only means that visual studio will pass those arguments when launching the `exe` for debug.

Double clicking on the exe will effectively pass **no** arguments, which means that this instruction:

```
string exeFilename = arguments[0];
```

will generate the exception you're seeing.

A quick solution would be to test for the number of arguments before proceding:

```
if(arguments.Lenght >= 4){
    //...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: That is not a solution at all, a solution is proper checking and actually passing the arguments

Comment: Yep, I didn't notice he was still accessing the array in the catch block (bad!). Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response. This code was just test code. Solution and suggestion work fine.